# Modeling data in table that have the same fields but different information

Tags: database-design

I am new to the world of data modeling, so this maybe a silly question. I have a table `user` that contains information about the user of a website. However, there are some `users` that have different contact information to what they want displayed on the website.

i.e. User A is the primary contact for us (dev team) but for the general public they want to contact another person.

Hence, the system needs to store the "public" contact person and the "private" contact person.

In our `user` table, is it better to

1. Create separate fields to store "public" and "private" contact information, or,
2. Create 2 tables - one for each - and have one-to-one relationship, or,
3. Create 1 table and have a one-to-many relationship with `user` and have an 'id' in the second table that identifies the public vs private?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
create table User
(
    userID int,
    userName nvarchar(100)
)

create table UserContactType
(
    userContactTypeID int,
    userContactTypeDesc nvarchar(100)
)

create table UserContact
(
    userContactID int,
    userID int,
    contactTypeID int,
    contactName nvarchar(100)
)
```

The `User` table has your users, the `UserContactType` table has your contact types (public, private, etc), and the `UserContact` table has however many contacts you need for each user, with the type specified.

Comment: Thanks - I have changed it slightly but kept the same idea.